# SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to made my first Push Notification script with using NodeJs and Socket.io
I found this tutorial:
http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

It's really helpfull but I stuck for few hours and can not go further.

I created both server.js and client.html files. When I call node server it's working and console is updated when someone enter etc. but while I visit my website on browser I do not see anything from my database.

While I try to run client.html on console (node client.html) I get following error:

```
root@Node:~# node client.html
/root/client.html:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <html>
                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
     at startup (node.js:117:18)
     at node.js:951:3
```

client.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <time></time>
        <div id="container">Loading ...</div>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // create a new websocket
        var socket = io.connect('http://46.101.226.135:8000/');
        // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
        var usersList = "<dl>";
        $.each(data.test_payout,function(index,user){
            usersList += "<dt>" + user.nick + "</dt>\n" +
                         "<dd>" + user.payout + "\n" +
                            "<figure> <img class='img-polaroid' width='50px' src='" + user.country + "' /></figure>"
                         "</dd>";
        });
        usersList += "</dl>";
        $('#container').html(usersList);

        $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
var app                 = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io                  = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs                  = require('fs'),
    mysql               = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray    = [],
    connection          = mysql.createConnection({
        host        : '46.105.14.241',
        user        : 'user',
        password    : 'password',
        database    : 'database',
        port        : 2083
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  console.log( err );
});

// create a new nodejs server ( http://46.101.226.135:8000/ )
app.listen(8000);

// on server ready we can load our client.html page
function handler ( req, res ) {
    fs.readFile( __dirname + '/client.html' , function ( err, data ) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log( err );
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end( 'Error loading client.html' );
        }
        res.writeHead( 200 );
        res.end( data );
    });
}

/*
*
* HERE IT IS THE COOL PART
* This function loops on itself since there are sockets connected to the page
* sending the result of the database query after a constant interval
*
*/
var pollingLoop = function () {

    // Make the database query
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM test_payout'),
        test_payout = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query


    // set up the query listeners
    query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
        console.log( err );
        updateSockets( err );

    })
    .on('result', function( user ) {
        // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
        test_payout.push( user );
    })
    .on('end',function(){
        // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
        if(connectionsArray.length) {
            pollingTimer = setTimeout( pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL );

            updateSockets({test_payout:test_payout});
        }
    });

};

// create a new websocket connection to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {

    console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
    // start the polling loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (!connectionsArray.length) {
        pollingLoop();
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf( socket );
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) {
            connectionsArray.splice( socketIndex, 1 );
        }
    });

    console.log( 'A new socket is connected!' );
    connectionsArray.push( socket );

});

var updateSockets = function ( data ) {
    // store the time of the latest update
    data.time = new Date();
    // send new data to all the sockets connected
    connectionsArray.forEach(function( tmpSocket ){
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , data );
    });
};
```

Comment: Node.js cannot run HTML code.  You're looking for a browser.

Comment: @SLaks It could work on localhost? I almost copy-paste in from tutorial and only changed database info and I use my server IP instead of localhost. This tutorial is bad or I miss something? ??

Comment: No; you need to open the HTML in a browser.

Comment: It's same when I visit: http://46.101.226.135:8000 or http://46.101.226.135:8000/client.html The problem is that only only thing that load is this : Loading... nothing more. No data from database etc.

Comment: You probably need to run server.js with node `node server.js`, then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to run

```
node server.js
```

Make sure you have *socket.io* and *mysql* installed via npm.

Then point your browser to http://localhost:8000 to get the client.html served from the node server.

It also seems that the database credentials are no longer valid as the output in the command line suggests.

```
{ [Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.] fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to run in on my DigitalOcean droplet. I had IP from them, listening is working becouse console is updated when I visit website in my browser. Connection is working I think becouse when I change connections details it thrown me an error while running node server.js in console. I think the problem is with client.html file and part that should stream data from database but I do not know where. Of course socket.io and mysql is installed.